# Cant get Java Timer working (javax.swing.Timer)

Tags: java, timer

So I'm trying to learn how the javax.swing.Timer works, but I can't get it to do a simple operation.  Basically all I'm trying to do is have the system print out "test2" every second, but it seems the actionPerformed method is never called. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("test 1");

        final Other o = new Other();

        class TimerListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                System.out.println("test2");
            }               
        }
        //test
        System.out.println("test 3");

        ActionListener listener = new TimerListener();

        //test
        System.out.println("test 4");

        final int DELAY = 1000;
        Timer t = new Timer(DELAY, listener);

        //test
        System.out.println("test 5");

        t.start();

        //test
        System.out.println("test 6");
    } 
}
```

This is the output that the above code produces:

test 1
test 3
test 4
test 5
test 6

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is exiting before the timer gets a chance to fire. Add a `Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000)` and you'll see the timer events.

Comment: You also should not use `javax.swing.Timer` off the EDT (strangely).

Answer (score 0):

A timer does not force your program to continue running after the main method has finished. Without starting another thread to run or ensuring that the main thread runs for a sufficient amount of time, the timer may never trigger.